# 1993 Ford Taurus LX 3.0 Catalytic Converter

Tags: ford, emissions, taurus

I've failed my smog test 3 times in a row within a week. They told me it was the EGR. So I changed my EGR Valve, EGR Solenoid, and my EGR Pressure sensor.  The vacuum lines running from the EGR Valve to the Solenoid are clean, no blockage.

I ran a OBD1 test, and the code 326 keeps popping up.

I checked the Catalytic Converter temps, before and after the Cat. Before it's about 300F and after, around 290F. I know it has to be hotter after to insure the pollutants are being cleaned before leaving the exhaust.

Any solutions?

Regards,
Frank

Comment: Whether or not your EGR is bad, it looks as though the cat is. there should be about a +200°F coming out the back of the cat after the engine is warmed up. With it being -10°F differential, this is definitely an issue.

Comment: Not sure we're you're from, but keep in mind that most states have "waiver" provisions that limit the amount of money motorists have to spend on emission repairs. In Colorado for instance, that amount is $750.


Not providing you with an answer. You definitely have an issue which hopefully others can help with. Just possibly some additional helpful info if you're hitting your repair budget for the year and just need some time figure this out.

Comment: @DucatiKiller - Good call! I was going to add that too my comment, but didn't for some reason. If I were a wagering man, I'd suggest the NOx is high (as related to the EGR).

Answer (score 2):

[OBD1 326](http://autorepair.about.com/library/a/1h/bl069h.htm) indicates that the EGR pressure sensor is reading pressure values that are out of the range deemed to be normal.

Along with the results of your pre/post-cat temperature test, this is strong evidence that the catalytic converter is clogged.

The solution would be to replace the catalytic converter.

Comment: @Frank   There's also this nice little writeup for you to refer to regarding bad cats.        http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/23503/how-can-i-tell-if-i-have-bad-cats   Cheers