# Bad pitting on carburetor causing small fuel leak

Tags: ford, carburetor, leak

I have a Motorcraft 2150 carb which has some pretty bad pitting on the main body. The pitting caused like two small holes and is causing fuel to slowly drip. I can only see the holes from the outside of the body and I'm not sure where it's leaking from on the inside...

There is also a hole on the bottom that looks like it was filled with jbweld or something, but the jbweld must've deteriorated when I rebuilt it (it's the picture with the throttle plates and power valve).

Are these safe to use jbweld on or something similar? What would be the best option, aside from replacing the entire carb?

Here are the pictures: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rsWW7.jpg

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[JB Weld is gasoline resistant](http://www.jbweld.com/pages/faqs).

I would disassemble the carburetor and inspect suspicious cracked components prior to applying any epoxy to the surfaces.

- Ensure components are absolutely clean
- inspect gasket surfaces for anomalies and remediate any issues you find
- validate suspected cracks

Back when I used to do this sort of thing to keep something on the road for the least possible financial investment I focused on cleaning the items thoroughly and visually inspecting them.  A magnifying glass or a loupe will work well for that.  I would also bake the parts at about 225°F after applying epoxy to accelerate the curing.  I've been told not to do that but have never taken the 'advice' and had great results.

You can also go air leak hunting by using this test.

- [Propane Test](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/24712/what-is-the-propane-test-and-how-is-it-carried-out)
- [Carb Cleaner Test](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/732/symptoms-of-lean-or-rich-carb-settings-on-a-motorcycle/23937#23937), there's a troubleshooting lean condition section toward the bottom of the answer.  It was written for motorcycles but applies to your situation where you confounded by unmetered air entering your system.

Comment: You can also bake the item *before* you put the material on them. It's called "outgassing". They do this with parts going to be powder coated to ensure there aren't any impurities on the part before they apply the powder. I'm sure it would bake something like what you are suggesting to cure the part ... maybe a bit hotter.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use an epoxy to plug the holes. It wouldn't take much to make it happen. When you are looking for epoxy, you want to ensure it is *fuel and solvent resistant*, like [VersaChem](http://www.autozone.com/sealants-glues-adhesives-and-tape/fuel-tank-and-radiator-epoxy/versachem-1-06-oz-plastic-gas-tank-and-radiator-repair-kit/382799_0_0/?checkfit=true) or [Travaco Marine Tex](http://www.westmarine.com/buy/travaco--marine-tex-repair-kit--P004_120_005_502) ... Mind you, I'm not recommending *either* of those products, just pointing them out so you know what to look for when trying to buy it.

Whatever you use, make sure it is *fully cured* before you reassemble everything. This may or may not work. I would expect whether it works or not, you'll want to get a new carburetor to replace this one anyway. You can go one of two ways: 1) get a completely new carb; 2) purchase a used one and rebuild it (or get it rebuilt).

Answer (score 1):

I have successfully used some aluminium 'soldering' or 'brazing' rods that you can heat with a propane blow torch to repair aluminium components like this.  The rods are made mainly of zinc and are sold by a number of companies. If done correctly, they will make a permanent fix on aluminium.

If you get some, have a practice on some scrap aluminium first.

See, for example - http://www.weldingtipsandtricks.com/aluminum-brazing-rods.html