# How exactly does running fuel-lean increase the temperature of ignition?

Tags: fuel-system, ignition, fuel-injection, temperature

I learned [in this question](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/25330/14003) that running an engine fuel-lean will increase the temperature of ignition, among other things such as causing problems with the catalytic converter. I have no idea how or why.

***How and why exactly does running fuel lean (or oxygen rich) increase the temperature of ignition?***

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have a qualitative description of what happens, but let's break it down to a smaller scale. When we talk about "temperature" of something, we are really talking about how fast the molecules are moving around and bouncing off each other. "Temperature" is really "kinetic energy". And it turns out that there are other types of energy besides moving around in space -- molecules can rotate, they can vibrate, and their electrons can get excited and move around relative to the nucleus. Each of these energies can also be a "temperature", so you can have translational temperature (what we normally think of), but you can have rotational temperature, vibrational temperature, and electronic temperatures.

Molecules exchange energy with one another by colliding into each other. When they do this, they also distribute the energy between them. How often they collide determines how quickly the energy becomes uniform, and this defines how quickly they reach what is called equilibrium. When all of the different temperatures are the same, the state is in equilibrium and we don't need to worry about keeping track of all of the different types of temperature. For most of the processes that would occur in an engine, there is more than enough time to reach equilibrium and so we don't need to worry too much about non-equilibrium effects.

Now, in chemical reactions, molecules break apart and form new ones. If the new ones have less energy, the difference in energy is released as heat. If the new ones have more energy, the reaction requires adding energy to make it happen. Obviously engines get hot, so the reactions in them release energy and we harness that energy to move the vehicle.

So, molecules break apart. And they break apart when they start vibrating so hard that the bonds between the atoms cannot hold them together anything. The only way to make the molecule vibrate is to have another molecule collide with it, with enough energy and an efficient enough transfer of energy to start the vibrations. And the energy has to be high enough that the vibration makes the molecules fall apart.

By changing the amount of fuel in the mixture, you are changing the types of collisions that can occur. And it's not exactly straight forward, but some molecules are better at exchanging energy with others. To make the fuel molecule fall apart, they need to collide with other fuel molecules with some energy of with other oxygen molecules with more energy. If you add more than the usual amount of oxygen (run lean), you also need to make that oxygen hotter so the molecules have more energy when they collide and can make the fuel vibrate hard enough to fall apart. Conversely, if you run fuel-rich, you have more fuel molecules that can collide with one another and fall apart, but fewer oxygen molecules for them to combine with and give off heat. This (and some other effects) makes the final flame temperature lower.

---

Based on some extended conversation on the question, let's put this all back into the context of an engine. For a direct-injection gas engine, the air is sucked into the cylinder, the piston compresses it, and then fuel is sprayed into the cylinder. A spark plug then triggers a spark in the chamber. This deposition of electrons gets the fuel-air mixture molecules all excited -- it actually ionizes the air (strips off electrons from the molecules) and this all adds a bunch of energy to the molecules. This energy is the initial energy required to start the combustion.

For a fuel-lean condition, I said it takes more energy to start the reaction and I phrased it in terms of a higher ignition temperature. The ignition temperature comes from that spark plug (for a cold engine -- hot engines will also contribute heat from the cylinders themselves). For normal operating conditions, spark plugs provide more than enough energy to ignite. As the operating condition gets leaner, the spark plug provides the same amount of energy -- but it is still enough energy to ignite. Eventually, for lean enough conditions, it won't be enough energy. This is a **lean misfire**.

Diesel engines work differently. For sake of argument, let's stick with a direct injection again. The cylinder fills with air, the piston compresses it, and the fuel is injected. There is no spark to initiate the reaction though. Diesel engines rely solely on creating high enough pressures to ignite the mixture. High pressure means high density and that means more collisions to spread the energy around (molecules don't need to go as far to hit one another). At any rate, the same ideas apply. In lean conditions, it would require a higher pressure to ignite. At ideal conditions, the engine compresses more than is exactly required, so when it runs fuel-lean, it still has enough compression to ignite. If you go so lean that the compression isn't high enough anymore, you will again get a **lean misfire**. Glow plugs can help all this by heating the cylinders and helping to add heat to the mixture and get the reactions going.

In either engine, once they have been running for awhile, the cylinder walls heat up and it requires less input (from sparks or from compression) to make the reaction occur. But for cold engines, it needs that initial energy deposition to get the reactions moving along. Many ECU's are set to burn fuel-rich when the engine is just starting because it is easier to ignite; as they heat up, the mixture becomes more lean and reduces emissions and fuel consumption. You may be familiar with manual chokes on things like lawn mowers -- the choke is what changes the fuel-air mixture and to get the motor started, you have to set the choke to be fuel-rich.

---

For those interested, based on the discussion we had in the various comment threads, I went ahead and gave a concrete example of how/why temperature can increase when the flame is fuel-lean. The conversation in chat is [bookmarked here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/340/conversation/lean-combustion-clarification).

Comment: Love your angle of approach on this.  +1 for unique an thoughtful.  TY!

Comment: It is an interesting angle of approach, though I'm not sure it answers the question completely. So you need to make the extra oxygen hotter, where does the extra heat come from?

Comment: @IhavenoideawhatI'mdoing Hmmm... I didn't interpret the question that way at all -- I took the question to be asking "How/why does a lean flame need to be hotter to ignite," not "How does an engine successfully operate at lean conditions." Did I misinterpret it?

Comment: As I understand it the underlying question is basically "why does an oxygen-rich flame burn hotter". Your answer explains why more heat is necessary to ignite a lean mixture, but I am still not sure where the extra heat comes from.

Comment: @IhavenoideawhatI'mdoing "Ignition temperature" is the heat required to start a flame and that's what the question is asking, and that is different from why does an oxygen-rich flame burn hotter (because it doesn't always, it burns hotter when you add some oxygen, but then not as hot if you add too much). That's a wholly different question -- ignition temperature (OP's question) is different from flame temperature (your question).

Comment: You are probably correct. I think some people, including myself, misinterpreted the question. The other two answers address increased cylinder temperature in the presence of a lean mixture, not ignition temperature.

Comment: You're both right in that my answer was in context of the previous conversation Max refers to. In that conversation we were talking about the temperature of combustion, not the ignition temperature.  So now I'm not sure I answered the right question.  Max, what did you mean,  the temperature of combustion, or the ignition temperature?

Comment: @cdunn Well, Max quoted your answer, which mentions ignition temperature specifically. Unless you didn't mean that.

Comment: I actually meant temperature of combustion. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: The energy is released because stronger bonds are formed:
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combustion

The amount of heat released depends on the type of the fuel and amount of it which is burnt in the process:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_of_combustion#Heat_of_combustion_tables

Surrounding temperature is just not related to the equation at all. The fuel is under normal conditions already above its flash point and under its auto-ignition temperature. There is a good article on wikipedia about this.
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_point

Comment: @EvrenYurtesen The surrounding temperature does matter though -- it affects whether there is enough energy to start the reaction at all and it affects the heat capacities of the fuel and air. Both of which affect whether the reaction will occur, how fast it will occur, and what the final temperature will be.

Comment: That said, the reason engines have spark plugs is provide enough energy to make sure the reaction happens and that answers @IhavenoideawhatI'mdoing question. The cylinders being hotter only helps later, once things heated up. But a cold engine can still burn lean. The spark plug has to deposit enough energy to make it work and that's where the ignition energy comes from (in a gas engine). In diesel engines, the initial compression has to be high enough and the cylinder walls preheated enough to have enough energy for the reaction to occur.

Comment: @tpg2114 1- We have to assume the surrounding temperature is within limits to start reaction because otherwise the question would not make sense. For gasoline this is between −43 °C (−45 °F) - 280 °C (536 °F) (according to wikipedia link I posted earlier). So this is irrelevant to this question.
2- I don't understand what you mean by 'heat capacity' The amount of heat generated is fixed by amount of fuel you burn. It does NOT depend on at what temperature you burn it. See tables here -> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_of_combustion

Comment: @EvrenYurtesen [Heat capacity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_capacity) is how much energy it takes to raise the temperature of something. So your fuel gives of 1 unit of heat. That will change the temperature of air by 10 units but change the temperature of fuel by 0.5 units. And the value of the heat capacity is dependent on temperature, so it is all a big, complex system that interacts. Temperature does matter very much.

Comment: @EvrenYurtesen And engines use spark plugs to start the reaction. We have to assume the fuel can vaporize, sure, but the reaction of gasoline at 10C is different from at 1000C. The energy from the spark plug is what triggers it initially.

Answer (score 7):

Funny you should ask this Max :)

First lets make sure of our definition. Running an engine lean means changing the air / fuel ratio to have more air than is ideal (14.7:1 air to fuel).

In my reading there are two effects. 
 First, the fuel is an atomized liquid which has a cooling effect on the combustion chamber. So less fuel, less cooling effect. 
Second, flames burn faster and hotter in the presence of more oxygen. More air relative to fuel than usual, means more oxygen than usual. So the flame burns hotter and faster than it should. Both are going to raise the temperature of the combustion chamber.

Great question, I was curious about this myself so I started to do some reading up on it.

I hope that helps!

Comment: Would it be correct to state that more fuel is burnt with the presence of more oxygen (or the existing fuel is burnt more completely, to be more accurate)? I don't believe adding more oxygen alone would make the flame hotter, would it?

Comment: @IhavenoideawhatI'mdoing When the equivalence ratio is exactly 1, all of the combustion is "complete" and that is what is called stoichiometric. So for any equivalence ratio of 1 or greater (lean), you burn up everything completely and there is no excess fuel. But lean flames do burn hotter just by adding more air, see [this figure for example](http://www.mdpi.com/coatings/coatings-05-00576/article_deploy/html/images/coatings-05-00576-g002-1024.png). It's a non-linear process -- there is less heat release because there is less fuel, but air heats up with less energy than fuel does.

Comment: Not sure I understand, and this also seems to contradict the newest answer. Could you elaborate on the mechanism by which the cylinder walls heat up more in a lean mixture than a perfectly stoichiometric? Does the extra oxygen conduct heat to the walls?

Comment: The latest answer is incorrect in several ways,  but more on that later.  The simple answer to your question is that the flame created is hotter because of the presence of more oxygen. A metal in contact with a hotter flame will be hotter. Hotter than it would be for a stoichiometric mixture.

Comment: @cdunn Well then why is the flame hotter? If the reaction between fuel and oxygen emit heat, then adding oxygen alone shouldn't increase the heat emitted (if the combustion is complete in both cases). So what's the underlying mechanism then?

Comment: The effect is repeatable and observable.  I have no idea why adding oxygen makes the flame hotter. I'll have to go do some more reading in this because now I'm curious as to why the effect happens.

Comment: @cdunn The reason it happens is an interplay between the heat released from the fuel from combustion and the amount of energy it takes to increase the temperature of fuel and air. Fuel takes more energy to get hotter (higher heat capacity) than air, so when there is more fuel, it takes more energy to raise the temperature of the mixture. When there is less fuel, it takes less energy to raise the temperature -- but there is also less fuel to release energy that causes the heating. It is a non-linear effect, so if you add a little more air, the temperature will increase because the

Comment: energy from the fuel that is there will raise the temperature of the mixture more. But too much air (or really, not enough fuel) and there isn't as much energy released so it doesn't get as hot. That's why in the figure in my comment up above, you see the temperature peaks for equivalence ratios between 1.1 and 1.3 depending on the fuel, and then decreases rapidly past that. And it decreases rapidly on the fuel-rich side because fuel takes more energy to heat up.

Comment: @tpg2114 I think you are explaining why a rich mixture runs cooler than stoichiometric, not why lean mixture runs hotter. If the combustion is complete as you said, then there should be the same amount of fuel in both stoichiometric and lean mixtures. So extra oxygen should cool, not heat. Unless "complete" combustion is not exactly complete.

Comment: @IhavenoideawhatI'mdoing It's hard to fit it all in comments here, but the reason why fuel-rich is cooler is the same reason why fuel-lean is hotter for a certain range. Available energy to heat stuff up and the amount of heat it takes to increase the temperature interplay in a non-linear way.

Comment: And yes, "complete" isn't really "complete" but that isn't the problem here. It's more like in a lean mixture, you get more "bang for your buck" in terms of combustion energy to temperature conversion. It takes less energy to heat the extra air and so even though you have less energy released, it is more effective at raising temperature. Until there just isn't enough energy to go around at all (too lean) and then it doesn't raise temperature as much.

Comment: @tpg2114 Hmm, I find the explanation to be a little vague. So the extra oxygen is brought to burning temperature but doesn't burn, total temperature should go down a little. Is the key in the fact that the heated air also helps conduct heat to the block ?

Comment: @IhavenoideawhatI'mdoing I think the back and forth in all the comment threads is getting a little crazy -- would you like to [discuss this further in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/340/the-pitstop) where we have some more room to type things out?

Comment: "...it's **cooler** than dry air of the **same temperature**" (emphasis mine). huh?

Comment: @cdunn You may want to look at my answer. Modern fuel-injected engines keep the fuel to air ratio balanced because too much fuel = hydrocarbon emissions and CO, too little fuel = hot combustion, and production of NOx, balanced combustion = CO2 (AKA clean exhaust). Of course we still need catalytic converter because even the best computer is only reacting to the sensor reading after the fact and there are small amounts of each of the above as the computer adjusts.

Comment: @DrewJordan Yeah, I could not figure out a good way to say what I obviously said so badly that first time, so I just removed it. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 5):

If you have ever seen an oxy-acetylene torch being used, you will have noticed that before the oxygen is turned on, the torch has a bright yellow flame. This is the fuel burning in a less than ideal amount of oxygen.  The flame is relatively cool and it produces a lot of soot.

When the oxygen is turned on, tthe flame turns blue and becomes hot enough to melt steel.

You may have also seen when too much oxygen is turned on, the flame goes out with a pop.

Fuel lean is the same as oxygen rich.

In an engine, the fuel wants to burn efficiently, but not too hot that it starts to melt the pistons, or maybe even violently explode, which will also cause damage.

From Wikipedia - 
A stoichiometric mixture unfortunately burns very hot and can damage engine components if the engine is placed under high load at this fuel–air mixture. Due to the high temperatures at this mixture, detonation of the fuel–air mix shortly after maximum cylinder pressure is possible under high load (referred to as knocking or pinging). Detonation can cause serious engine damage as the uncontrolled burning of the fuel air mix can create very high pressures in the cylinder. As a consequence, stoichiometric mixtures are only used under light load conditions. For acceleration and high load conditions, a richer mixture (lower air–fuel ratio) is used to produce cooler combustion products and thereby prevent detonation and overheating of the cylinder head.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air–fuel_ratio

Sorry I can't get the link to work - copy and paste into browser.

Comment: yes I realized it now. Deleting the comment.

Comment: @NathanL. I hope you don't mind me correcting you, but a violent explosion is exactly what you don't want in an internal combustion engine.  That is why engines have knock sensors on them to stop damage from explosions.  What is required is a controlled flame front that passes through the fuel to give a steady expansion of the gases.  I am pleased that you think my answer is generally correct however.

Comment: @NathanL The fact that you refer to it as an explosion shows that you do not understand what is going on.  Please read the extract from Wikipedia that I have added to my answer.  The fuel is always ignited before the piston reaches TDC.

Comment: @NathanL I have added a reference to the Wikipedia page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35050/discussion-between-nathan-l-and-handyhowie).

Answer (score 2):

The temperature engine rises because the ignition of the fuel is **slower**. It takes longer for the fuel to burn because there is less of it.

The fuel itself has the same amount of BTUs available by burning it whether you use extra oxygen or not. PERIOD. When you blow on the coals in your fire, they get hotter but burn faster. They release the same amount of heat, but in a much shorter period of time.

Imagine your cylinder as a cabin in the winter. If you took a log and burned it in one minute, the items near the stove where that log was burning would heat up significantly and maybe melt, but most of the heat would go out through the chimney. If you only had one log per hour, the room would be very cold most of the time. Take that same log and burn it slowly for an hour before replacing it with another and less heat goes out through the exhaust and stays in the room.

The reason the engine gets hotter is that the slower burning fuel transfers more heat to the surrounding parts of the engine.

Comment: So, we're talking about a lean condition where there is more air relative to a 14.7:1 desired AFR. Are you saying that adding more air without adding more oxygen will make the engine run cooler?

Comment: Are you saying fuel burns slower in an oxygen rich environment?

Comment: @handyhowie I'm saying the fuel burns slower in a fuel-lean environment. Usually lean doesn't mean *more oxygen*; it means *less fuel*.

Comment: @cdunn That depends on if there is enough oxygen to burn all the fuel present, doesn't it? And no, if there is sufficient oxygen to burn all the fuel, more air won't cool the engine. It will cause the combustion temperature to be lower and slower giving more time to transfer heat to the engine during the combustion process.

Comment: Nathan - The two are relative to each other.  In an engine, if you don't put in a controlled amount of fuel to keep the mixture slightly fuel rich, then the fuel will burn very hot and cause damage to the engine.  It can also explode rather burn in a controlled manner.

Comment: @HandyHowie Using a rich mixture may be desirable for a performance engine that is frequently pressed to its limits in a race on an enclosed circuit, but this is definitely not the case for normal cars driven on the roads. Rich mixtures result in pollution in the form of hydrocarbons and carbon monoxide. Most countries have laws limiting outputs of those.

Comment: Nathan - Sorry, but this is the case for all gasoline engines.  I never said very rich, I said slightly rich.

Answer (score 2):

Stopped here after looking around without too much success for a good explanation about overheating due to lean burning in an engine.  Here my two cents about the subject:

1- It is well known and documented that peak or maximum combustion temperature is lower as the atmospheric air/fuel ratio deviates from stochiometric, so a lean combustion generates a lower peak temperature as compared to stochiometric, 14.7:1 for gasoline, for example.  Although a lean combustion could be more complete, the peak combustion temperature is lower due to the cooling effect of the additional inert atmospheric nitrogen in a lean setup. 
Remember that atmospheric air contains a significant amount of inert Nitrogen and that old Popular Science issue telling about Smokey Yunick's design of an Adiabatic Engine and his attempts to device a Nitrogen removal filter?

2- Also well known that the speed of any chemical reaction will slow down as the concentration of the reactive are decreased.  Also expected because as the fuel molecules get farther from each other, then less chance to promote a chained reaction, thus significantly reducing the speed of the combustion.

3- Also, the total amount of heat generated is decreased while burning lean as expected due to less fuel or caloric content being involved in a lean combustion.  So why then the unexpected outcome of engine overheating?

4- It is not a matter of less cooling available from the evaporation of the liquid fuel, it is more related to the overall energy balance in the engine.  As the combustion gets slower, a bigger portion of heat energy is unable to be converted as shaft work energy and thus is mostly expelled as wated heat thru the exhaust port.  Similarly happens if your ignition timing is retarded far away from optimal...the lean combustion heat, althougth being less,  is unable to be properly converted to shaft work because the combustion was so late that it is out of sync with the movement of the pistons.  That is why Toyota advanced the ignition timing in their earlier Lean Burning Engines when activated that mode. So then, where goes the heat that cannot be converted to shaft work?...due to Energy Conservation laws it will show somewhere...well, some of it will go to heat the engine parts, mostly the exhaust portion of the cylinder heads, where there are less chance to be removed by the cooling system, thus building up and overheating the engine itself.

Basically, as the combustion gets leaner, the engine starts to loose some of its efficiency to convert combustion energy to mechanical energy and thus works closer to a simple fuel furnace suitable for heating itself.  Symptoms of this type of overheating are burnt exhaust valves, different tone in exhaust noise, and even incandescent exhaust manifold, similar to an engine running with a very retarded ignition timing.
In the case of nitrous injection, despite the nitrous have plenty of cooling effect, if accidentally the combustion gets too lean due to a fuel shortage, the engine literally melts.  In this case, despite the fuel ratio was way too lean, the amount of fuel involved or caloric content could still be significantly more than in a normal engine, so even more heat energy will not be converted to shaft work, so then be available to heat up the engine.

Answer (score 1):

You all forget something, the reason slight leanburn can be hotter than stochiomnetric ratios is very simple. It has to do with the injection of the fuel. For stochiometric ratio to work as intended every single oxygen atom would have to pair up perfectly with a fuel molecule before ignition. That just isn't possible, so you have unburned fuel molecules in your combustion.

By adding slightly more air to the mix you can ensure that all of your fuel combusts to a higher degree, which in term will raise the temperature of your combustion, add too much and the heat capacity of the excess air will lower the temperature.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answers are incorrect. Because the question assumption is incorrect. First we have to decide hotter compared to what? and also we need to know this is a fact, is it really hotter or is it a myth? in addition the amount of the fuel/oxygen ratio is important, is this condition always true for all lean ratios? Perhaps the correct question is why the "slightly" lean mixture is hotter than "slightly" rich mixture perhaps?

The thermal energy output from fuel is simply related to how much of it you burn. You burn less, less heat is generated. You burn more, more heat is generated. As simple as that. Here what creates the heat is the energy stored in the fuel (for our example other factors such as pressures, frictions etc. are not important).

If you are comparing a rich mixture with lean mixture, of course the lean mixture will have higher energy output because you would convert all the fuel into energy. (more burned fuel = more heat) But it still depends on your mixture ratios, because if you have almost no fuel in your mixture, obviously then it wont generate so much energy.

If you are comparing an ideal mixture with lean mixture, then I think it should be even cooler (less thermal energy generated from combustion) since you would be getting less fuel and more oxygen into the chamber.

Comment: This answer asserts that the heat produced is only related to how much fuel is being burned.  That is not true.  Burn the same amount of fuel in the presence of more oxygen and you will get more heat.

Comment: That is only true if your original burning process did not have enough oxygen to burn the fuel completely. The heat generated is purely related to the amount of burned fuel + type of fuel. You can see easily from the heat of combustion tables of different types of fuels. The value does NOT depend on oxygen amount.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_of_combustion#Heat_of_combustion_tables

Comment: Ahhh, interesting. Sounds like I have more reading to do,  starting with the link you provided.

Comment: @cdunn The confusion may be that "heat" is not "temperature" in the combustion world. Heat is energy, and Evren's statement about energy released is correct. But how that energy gets turned into temperature is based on heat capacities of the mixture. And the heat capacity of the mixture depends on it's temperature and it's composition (it's not a trivial combination of effects). Tying back to my answer, the heat capacity is related to how much freedom a molecule has to move, rotate, vibrate and electronically excite.

Comment: One of our competing research labs has a pretty good site [where you can see the equations and examples](http://elearning.cerfacs.fr/combustion/n7masterCourses/adiabaticflametemperature/index.php) and you can [also compute flame temperatures for different fuels](http://elearning.cerfacs.fr/combustion/tools/adiabaticflametemperature/index.php) or [watch lectures on the topic](http://elearning.cerfacs.fr/combustion/index.php).

Comment: @tpg2114 the heat capacity is irrelevant because it is "a measurable physical quantity equal to the ratio of the heat added to (or removed from) an object to the resulting temperature change." Quoted from wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_capacity
I think you are probably talking about 'Specific Heat' "the heat capacity per unit mass of a material." (also from wikipedia)
So the question boils down to how much heat we should add to mixture to increase it is temperature to a certain value and you are right, you need more slightly more energy to do it when mixture is warmer but...

Comment: @EvrenYurtesen Be careful with words like irrelevant -- specific heat is just heat capacity divided by the mass. One is an extensive property, one is an intensive property and you can use either one when looking at a thermodynamic system. So if one is relevant, the other is also and it's just a choice of reference frame.

Comment: The reason the temperature is important is because reactions proceed forward (and backward) based on the temperature and their [activation energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activation_energy). If the temperature is too low, not enough reactions occur. So the amount of energy released when fuel reacts is constant, but how much fuel reacts depends on the temperature, and the temperature depends on the heat capacity (specific or otherwise) of the mixture.

Comment: @tpg2114 but we are talking about huge sums of energy and tiny amounts of mass to increase the temperature of. You can only see why it is irrelevant if you put it into numbers. According to engineeringtoolbox.com the specific heat of gasoline = 2.22kJ/kg.K and air = 1.00kJ/kg.K. Here we see it is easier to increase temperature of ir. But the air fuel ratio is 14 to 1 in an engine already so changing it slightly will not effect the end result that much. -> http://www.turbobygarrett.com/turbobygarrett/airfuel_ratio_tuning_rich_vs_lean

Comment: @tpg2114 in a car engine once the fuel is ignited by the ignition source, a chain-reaction occurs and this consumes all the fuel or oxygen whichever ends first. Please provide a reference which tells otherwise. When the lambda value is calculated, the surrounding temperature is not considered, the mixture being rich or lean purely depends on fuel and air mixture
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air%E2%80%93fuel_ratio#Air.E2.80.93fuel_equivalence_ratio_.28.CE.BB.29

It would be nice if you can support your argument with some numbers and references. Because all of these depend on measurable values.