# Catalytic converter tests

Tags: catalytic-converter

Got a Mk 6 Fiesta with an engine light on, and showing a code for under performing cat or oxygen sensor.

Connected a vacuum gauge to my intake port and it's pulling a very good level of 25. Might run it again with the air filter out.

Just curious about how common it is for a cat to pass a vacuum or pressure test, but still be internally broken?

Which test would rule that out?

Thanks

Comment: Check the oxygen sensor - check for supply, check the wires and test the sensor.

Comment: [Does this answer help you?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/23520/4152) ... also, check the answer above it as it is more complete than my answer.